# What does this C function return?

Tags: c, function, return

```
int f(int n)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(int)*8; i++, n >>= 1)
        c = (n & 0x01)? c+1: c;
    return c;
}
```

It's an exercise I found on my book, but I really don't get It!

Comment: Which specific part do you have a question about?

Comment: It returns an `int`. The exact value depends on the argument passed to the function.

Comment: @CarlNorum, I don't get what this part does:
c = (n & 0x01)? c+1: c;

Comment: To figure this out, take each piece of the function and make sure you understand it. The function is simple enough that you could "run" it on a piece of paper, which should help your understanding.

Comment: @user1100421, I address that in my answer below.

Comment: Just a note that this function will loop once for each bit position in `n`, even if they are all zero. Other functions will only loop once for each bit actually set. See [How to count the number of bits set in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/109036/597607).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It counts the number of bits set in the passed in parameter `n` (assuming your machine has 8-bit bytes).  I'll comment inline with your code (and fix the terrible formatting):

```
int f(int n)
{
    int i;     // loop counter
    int c = 0; // initial count of set bits is 0

    // loop for sizeof(int) * 8 bits (probably 32), 
    // downshifting n by one each time through the loop
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8; i++, n >>= 1) 
    {
        // if the current LSB of 'n' is set, increment the counter 'c',
        // otherwise leave it the same
        c = (n & 0x01) ? (c + 1) : c;  
    }

    return c;  // return total number of set bits in parameter 'n'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is doing a bitwise and - turning on bits off and off bits on.

Comment: No, that's not what it's doing.

Comment: The bitwise "and" operation does not "turn on bits off and off bits on".  That's a "not" operation.